# Error in DATABASE_VERSION of SQLiteOpenHelper on my android app

Tags: android

Everytime my database change in my app, when I run the application i got an error,
I think its not changing the DATABASE_VERSION or something like that.
Because i can only restart the app when i change value of this attribute:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 16;
```

Here is my code:

```
public class BaseDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String TBL_AGENDA = "agenda";
    public static final String AGENDA_ID = "_id";
    public static final String AGENDA_NOME = "nome";
    public static final String AGENDA_ENDERECO = "endereco";
    public static final String AGENDA_TELEFONE = "telefone";
    public static final String AGENDA_ESTADO = "estado";
    public static final String AGENDA_IDESTADO = "idEstado";
    private static final int count = 0;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "agenda.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 16;


    private static final String CREATE_AGENDA = "create table " +
            TBL_AGENDA + "( " + AGENDA_ID       + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + 
                                AGENDA_NOME     + " text not null, " +
                                AGENDA_ENDERECO + " text not null, " +
                                AGENDA_ESTADO + " text not null, " +
                                AGENDA_IDESTADO + " integer not null, " +
                                AGENDA_TELEFONE + " text not null);";

    public BaseDAO(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(CREATE_AGENDA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBL_AGENDA);
        onCreate(db);   
    }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you really need onUpgrade()?

Comment: Maybe the current DATABASE_VERSION is **lower** than the greatest one you used? I'd simply reset it to **1**. Then uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: At the time I stop my app and run it again...my app stops...im getting nothing in the LOG CAT...but if i increment manually at the code the database version...i can start the app but without any database...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're changing the database schema that's why the app doesn't work unless you change that database version. According to developer's:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

> If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.

Comment: yes...I know...but where I have to increment the database version ?

Comment: @Daniel in your `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 16;` increase that number

Comment: but where ? In the declaration ? Like 16++?

Comment: @Daniel No, you can just make it 17 :D

Comment: lol ok...I know that works...but everytime that I will run my app i will have to open my code and change the value of the database version...and that is the thing that i dont wanna do...understand ?